# Popup resizing based on orientation

Tags: ios, swift, resize, orientation

I have assignment to make a resizable popup based on the device orientation. I am instantiating it over the window like this.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let popOver = DeletePopUpViewController(nibName: "DeletePopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
popOver?.loadViewIfNeeded()
popOver?.view.frame = window!.frame
window?.addSubview(popOver!.view)
```

I have added constraints in the IB, since my task for now wasn't to be resizable. Now I need to transfer my constraints to the code, and this is what bothers me. I was able to detect orientation change with observer like -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

@objc private func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {
         //code to implement constraints and size in landscape.
    }    
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown {
        //code to implement constraints and size in portrait.
    }    
}
```

Could you please give me some guidelines where to start from since I am fairly new to Swift and haven't done a lot of constraints in code. Also article would be helpful as well. Basically every help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer below code:**

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let popOver = DeletePopUpViewController(nibName:   "DeletePopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
popOver?.loadViewIfNeeded()
popOver.tag = 1000
popOver?.view.frame = window!.frame
window?.addSubview(popOver!.view)


@objc private func rotated() {    
    let window = appDelegate.window!

    if let popup = window.viewWithTag(1000){
        popup.frame = window.bounds
    }
}
```

**Update: With autolayout**

```
  func addPopoverView(){
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let rootVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        let viewToAdd = UIView()
        let count = rootVC.view.subviews.count
        rootVC.view.insertSubview(viewToAdd, at: count)
        viewToAdd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewToAdd.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootVC.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewToAdd.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootVC.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewToAdd.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootVC.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewToAdd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootVC.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true            
        viewToAdd.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

Comment: That would be helpful for creating popup manager for different popups, which I will be making, thanks, but still the problem with constraints from code is my first concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need this to your popview, that will automatically resize

```
let popOver = DeletePopUpViewController(nibName:   "DeletePopUpViewController", bundle: nil)
        popOver?.loadViewIfNeeded()
popOver?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
        popOver?.view.frame = window!.frame
        window?.addSubview(popOver!.view)
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a helpful start! :)